# construct my own strcat function with arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strcat

I am trying to write a function that works like strcat, I dont get any error when compiling the code. the problem is when calling the function it didnt append the elements in the second array to the first one. when I print the first array it still the same. any suggesting?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strcat1(char *dest, char *src);

char *strcat1(char *dest, char *src) {
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("i0=%d, j0=%d\n", i, j);

    i = strlen(dest);
    j = strlen(src);
    for (int z = 0; z < j; z++) {
        dest[z + i + 1] = src[z];    
    }
}

int main() {
    char str1[100];
    char str2[30];
    printf("put the first string:\n");
    fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
    printf("\ninput the second string\n");
    fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);
    strcat1(str1, str2);
    printf("%s", str1);
}
```

Comment: You should overwrite the \0 in the first string e.g. ABC\0  CDEF\0 ABCDEF\0

Comment: You forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*.

Comment: AFAICT: Your +1 in dest[...] skips the \0 which terminates the dest string.

Comment: `dest[z+i+1]` should be `dest[z+i]`

Comment: Off-topic: potential memory overrun in function `main`. Better limit input size on `str1`, to leave space for `strcat1` to work in: `fgets(str1, sizeof(str1) - sizeof(str2) + 1, stdin);`

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with your `strcat1` function:

- The prototype should be `char *strcat1(char *dest, const char *src);` as the function does not modify the source string.
- The characters should be copied at offset `z + i` into the `dest` array. You currently copy the source string after the null terminator, so nothing appears when you print the destination array after the copy.
- You must copy the null terminator too, to ensure proper termination of the destination array.
- You must return the pointer to the destination array.
- The index variables should have type `size_t`, that has a larger positive range than type `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```
char *strcat1(char *dest, const char *src) {
    size_t i = strlen(dest);
    size_t j = strlen(src);
    for (size_t z = 0; z <= j; z++) {
        dest[z + i] = src[z];    
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Note that you can implement this function with pointers, without `strlen` and with a single scan of the source string:

```
char *strcat1(char *dest, const char *src) {
    char *p = dest;
    while (*p)
        p++;
    while ((*p++ = *src++) != '\0')
        continue;
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but why I need to use const in the arguments? didn't get it

Comment: @sam0101: A `const` qualified pointer cannot be used to modify the object it points to. `const` qualifying all pointer arguments that are not used to modify the object they point to is a good programming practice: it allows more optimisations and helps the programmer structure code along this distinction. The compiler will complain if you pass a `const` qualified pointer to a function that modifies an object, preventing unwanted side effects. This process is called constification. All functions in the Standard C library follow this convention.

Answer (score 1):

str1 is finished by a '\0'.

strlen returns length of string not including the terminating null character.

So for example if string is "toto" then strlen(string) is 4.

In memory :

```
string[0] = 't'
string[1] = 'o'
string[2] = 't'
string[3] = 'o'
string[4] = '\0'
```

But you are writing at dest[z+i+1] so in my example.
string[z + 4 + 1] whitch is string[5].
So after the '\0'.

The result will be : "toto\0string2".

But because printf %s stop reading pointer at \0, you only see "toto".

Try to replace

```
dest[z+i+1]
```

by

```
dest[z+i]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion in given answer so far.
It comes from fact that the strings read by `fgets` are not only `null character` terminated but also contain `LINE_FEED` character.

1) Coppying

```
dest[z+i+1]=src[z];
```

has to be performed as:

```
dest[z+i-1] = src[z];
```

to eliminate '`\n' == 0x0A`

or preserving `'\n'` as:

```
dest[z+i] = src[z];
```

2) We also have to properly terminate the concatenated string.
Knowing that it `i` and `j` take under account '\n' characters we have to terminated string accordingly:

```
   dest[i+j] = '\0' ;
```

3) In C90, the prototype is:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

The `strcat()` function shall return the pointer `dest`; the function has no failure mode and no error return.

The improved program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* strcat1(char* dest, const char* src);

char* strcat1(char* dest, const char* src){
   size_t i;
   size_t j;
   size_t z;

   i = strlen(dest);   //  Note: '\n' is included in the length count
   j = strlen(src);    //  Note: '\n' is included in the length count

   printf("i0=%zu, j0=%zu %X\n ", i, j, src[j-1] );

   for(z=0; z < j; z++){
        dest[z+i] = src[z];    
   }
   dest[i+j] = '\0' ;

  return dest;
}

int main(void){

   char str1[100];
   char str2[30];

   printf("put the first string:\n");
   fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);

   printf("\ninput the second string\n");
   fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);

   strcat1(str1,str2);

   printf("\n%s", str1);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
put the first string:                                                                                                                           
1234                                                                                                                                            

input the second string                                                                                                                         
567890                                                                                                                                          
i0=5, j0=7 A                                                                                                                                    

1234                                                                                                                                            
567890
```

Comment: OP is "trying to write a function that works like strcat". [strcat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) does not strip off the trailing `\n`, and for a good reason. It is not the responsibility of strcat to mitigate the features/quirks of fgets.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Thank you for your comment! This is very true. It is not the job of the `strcat` to mitigate the content of the strings. Answer  has been improved accordingly.